# Fazer requisição ajax com IP do usuário

Tags: ajax, request

Quando faço a requisição em algum site vi ajax, pega o IP do servidor como requisitante, tem como eu colocar o IP do usuário como o responsável pela requisição?

Comment: Só vai pegar o IP do servidor se você estiver fazendo a requisição no lado do servidor

Comment: Utilize essa API para enviar o IP do usuário para o servidor: http://ip-api.com/

Answer (score -2):

Segue exemplo:

```
$('#enviar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://ip-api.com/json"
    }).success(function (msg) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
            data: {
                ip: msg.query
            }
        }).success(function (e) {
            $('#url')[0].innerHTML = e;
            $('#ip')[0].innerHTML = msg.query;
            alert('Salvo com sucesso.');
        }).error(function (e) {
            alert('Ocorreu um erro. Mensagem: ' + e);
        });


    }).error(function (msg) {
        alert('Erro: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

[Clique aqui para abrir exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/giancarlodebian/o4tjvL0d/)

Comment: Ah entendi.. Mas ai no caso, eu teria que saber como a página requisitada trata o IP? Minha requisição é _Cross Domain_..

Comment: Não precisa porque é uma API